# Change default font of an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-typeface

What I do is:

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface)
```

Let's say the font only has **English** letters:
Anything else I type is shown in `Typeface.DEFAULT`

**Question:**
Is it possible to change the default font to another one?

Comment: "Is it possible to change the default font to another one?" -- um, by calling `setTypeface()`. You are doing that already. "Let's say the font only has English letters" -- then there is a bug in the font. Pick a better font.

Comment: That's not an option for me since the user chooses the font. There is no way to do it?

Comment: "That's not an option for me since the user chooses the font" -- find some tool or library that allows you to examine the font. If it is missing lots of possibly-relevant glyphs, warn the user that their chosen font will not work that well.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like textview

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
```

Otherwise try this way, first create this method

```
public void setFonts(EdiText tv) {
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/myfont.ttf");
  tv.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

then set it to your edittext

```
ClassName.setFonts(urEditText);
```

https://github.com/omadahealth/TypefaceView